# FtpWebRequest move file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ftp

I am putting together a simple app and I have it working for uploading, downloading, deleting files using FtpWebRequest.  But I cannot find how to move a file using FtpWebRequest. What is the simplest way to move a file from one dir to another without using another external dependancy?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Create a FtpWebRequest with the source file name, set the Method-Property of the FtpWebRequest to Use System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename and set the RenameTo-Property of the FtpWebRequest to the new file name.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("oldName");
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
request.RenameTo = "newName";
```

Comment: Don't you need to call GetResponse?

Comment: @notfed: Preferably... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx